# ko.computed by not using values in Viewmodel od knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

is it possible to us ko.computed by using values which are not observable in viewmodel.

```
    self.EnableSave = ko.computed(function () {

        if ($('#PoolName').val().toString().trim().length > 0 && $('#Description').val().toString().trim().length > 0 && self.MatrixList().length > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason you couldn't use non-observables in a computed. However, only changes to observables would trigger the computed to fire. In this case, the computed would only reevaluate when MatrixList changes.

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer. It made me understand the working of computed. So, you are saying that it will work but it will get triggered only when the MatrixList changes.

Comment: if during the first evaluation of your computed the first or second condition are false your computed will not be aware about the MatrixList observable.